# WPF (XAML - Data Binding - Find Ancestor)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, telerik

I faced a prob where I can't seem to bind a value from my ViewModel.. The code is something like this..

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
       ...
       DataContext = "{Binding thisViewModel}"
       ItemSource = "{Binding item1}"
       ... >

   <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
             ....
             DataMemberBinding = "{Binding insideItem1}">

         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>

             <Run Text = "{Binding Path = DataContext.item2,
                               RelativeSource = {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                   AncestorType="{x:Type telerik:RadGridView"}, 
                                   AncestorLevel = 1}}"/>

              .....

      </<telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

The one that has the binding problem is the **item2** inside the **"Run Text"** part. **item2** is another property inside **thisViewModel** just like **item1**. Can anyone enlightens me on this matter? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: do you see any binding error in output window?

Comment: nope there isn't.. it just doesn't populate the value.. I've cross checked it on my viewModel side.. The property has the value that I want too

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you define your ViewModel as StaticResource, then bind it in this way:

```
<Run Text = "{Binding Path=DataContext.item2 Source={StaticResource MyDataContext}}"/>
```

Hope it helps! Have a great day!

Comment: Interesting idea. Nice clean way to handle ancestor bindings.

Comment: I'd just note that it should be changed to `<Run Text = "{Binding Path=item2 Source={StaticResource MyDataContext}}"/>`. With the DataContext (ViewModel) being defined as MyDataContext, it isn't needed in the Path.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will take a look into that... but I'm more interested to understand why isn't  the above binding working.. Would appreciate if anyone could point that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing comma and your some unnecessary (and slightly muddled) quotes. Additionally the Run element can't be used on its own like that as I understand it, but should be included within something like a TextBlock, or a Paragraph within a FlowDocument. A corrected version of your code is

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.item2,
                    Mode=OneWay,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView},
                        AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

If you don't have need of the Run functionality specifically, you could just use a TextBlock on its own

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.item2,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView},
                    AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
```

A slightly simpler alternative if it works with your layout is

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.item2,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}"/>
```

Comment: haha.. noted about the comma... But it isn't working though :/

Comment: I can't think what the issue could be. The code I posted is definitely a valid binding for a Text property. I'm not really familiar with the Run class - are you sure you're using it correctly? Try changing the Run to a TextBlock and see if that displays, it should at least prove whether the binding is working.

Comment: I've had a look into it and as I understand it the Run class needs to be contained in another element such as a TextBlock, Paragraph of a FlowDocument, etc. I'll update my answer - try the new one.

Comment: i see... I've tried that as well... but it doesn't seem working either... I was thinking could it be something to do with Telerik?

Comment: I've not used Telerik but it's a possibility. The fact that you're not seeing any binding errors in your output suggests it is actually binding. Try adding Mode=OneWay (I'll update my answer to show you where)

Comment: Also try moving the TextBlock outside of the telerik:RadGridView to see if it shows up, again just to test if it is binding

Comment: o.. i see.. anyway, i've tried setting Mode=TwoWay but it's not working. Does TwoWay already covered OneWay's capability? Yes, when it is outside the RadGridView the text does shows up haha... man...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108546/discussion-between-tone-and-drillfreak100).